# Multi-dimensional Array - new variable query

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

long time reader first time query, with a multi dimensional array question.  I was wondering if anyone can help with a rather straight forward request I am struggling with? I wish to create a new variable (names) which will include all the names from the below array. I have an array similar to below -

```
myArray = [
["one","Bob", 42],
["two","Jerry",65],
["three","Tom",42],
["four","Dave",34],
["five","Sarah",55]
];
```

As best as I have learnt to assign my new variable it should look similar to the below, however I am wondering how to add Jerry, Tom, Dave & Sarah to my new names variable? -

```
var names = myArray [0][1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array.map(..)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for that, here is an example:

```js
const myArray = [
['one', 'Bob', 42],
['two','Jerry',65],
['three','Tom',42],
['four','Dave',34],
['five','Sarah',55]
];

const names = myArray.map(arr => arr[1]);
console.log(names);
```

Comment: That is great! However if I wished to just take for example - Bob, Dave, Sarah and assign to a new variable?

Comment: @Kakarot12 You can use [`Array.filter(..)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for that, how you use it depends on what is the logic for keeping or removing names. Here is an example that removes `Jerry` from the array: `names = names.filter(name => name !== 'Jerry')`.

Comment: Thank you! As you can see in my above example I have stated my new variable name's as : ```var names = array [0][1]``` (to include just Bob). Should I wish to add one further name (for example Tom) to this new variable 'names' can I simply add to my ori

Comment: @Kakarot12 I don't understand exactly what you're trying to do. *to include Bob* in not that clear, how do you want to figure out which of the values contains the `string` **Bob**, based on the array index, based on string comparison `myArray[0][n] === 'Bob'`, etc. ? You can find out how to manipulate arrays [FROM HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Answer (score 0):

You can `Array.prototype.map()` over `myArray` and create a new array with only the secend element of each array inside of `myArray`

```js
const myArray = [
  ["one", "Bob", 42],
  ["two","Jerry",65],
  ["three","Tom",42],
  ["four","Dave",34],
  ["five","Sarah",55]
];

const names = myArray.map( elem => elem [1])

console.log(names)
```